# Implicit Differentiation of this function

Tags: calculus

[If 
$x^2 + xy + y^3 = 1$,
 find the value of

$y'''$
 at the point where 
x = 1.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBZm6.jpg)

Am i going the right direction, if so how will know what is the values of y' and y''

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easier, I think, to avoid division as much a possible, thus:

With

$x^2 + xy + y^3 = 1, \tag 1$

and $x = 1$,

$1 + y + y^3 = 1; \tag 2$

thus

$y(y^2 + 1) = y^3 + y = 0; \tag 3$

thus, if we assume $y \in \Bbb R$,

$y = 0; \tag 4$

that is, we have

$(x, y) = (1, 0). \tag 5$

We find, taking $d/dx$ of (1),

$2x + y + xy' + 3y^2y' = 0; \tag 6$

with $x = 1$ and $y = 0$,

$2 + y'(1) = 0, \tag 7$

so

$y'(1) = -2; \tag 8$

differentiating (6) yields

$2 + y' + y' + xy'' + 6y(y')^2 + 3y^2y'' = 0, \tag 9$

or

$2 + 2y' + xy'' + 6y(y')^2 + 3y^2 y'' = 0; \tag{10}$

we insert the values of $x, y, y'$:

$2 + 2(-2) + y'' = 0, \tag{11}$

whence

$y''(1) = 2; \tag{12}$

we now differentiate (10) one more time and obtain

$2y'' + y'' + xy''' + 6(y')^3 + 12yy'y'' + 6yy'y'' + 3y^2y''' = 0, \tag{13}$

or

$3y'' + xy''' + 6(y')^3 + 18yy'y'' + 3y^2y''' = 0; \tag{14}$

inserting the values for $x$, $y$, $y'$ and $y''$ yields

$3(2) + y''' + 6(-2)^3 = 0, \tag{15}$

or

$y''' = 42. \tag{16}$

This could obviously go on forever but I'll stop here.

Comment: in the 9th step shouldnt it just be 6yy' without the square?

Comment: @EldarRahim: no, because by the chain rule $d/dx(3y^2) = 6yy'$.  Then the other factor of $y'$ yields $6y(y')^2$ for the whole kaboodle.

Comment: Wow. Great . Thanks. Didn't see that part

Answer (score 1):

First put $x=1$ into $x^2+xy+y^3=1$ to find $y$
$$x=1 \to 1+1y+y^3=1 \\y^3+y=0 \\y(y^2+1)=0 \\y=0\\(1,0)$$ your work point's is $(1,0)$

now 
$$x^2+xy+y^2=1 \to \\2x+1y+xy'+3y^2y'=0 \text{ put (1,0) }\\
2(1)+1(0)+y'+3(0)y'=0 \to y'=-2 $$ can you go on  ?

Comment: if y' is a constant, then y'' is 0, therefore y''' is 0 too. But 0 is the wrong answer

Comment: @EldarRahim: you think not correct , you can find $y'$ by implicit derivation ,,,is it zero too ?now

Comment: @Khosrotash:  you made an arithmetic error 'twixt $2x + 1y + xy' + 3y^2y' =0$ and $2 + 1 + y' + 3y' = 0$, which should be $2(1) + 1(0) + y' = 0$ or $y'(1) = -2$.